# ADF - Bind multiple data controls to a Carousel Item

Tags: carousel, oracle-adf, jspx

I am currently trying to bind 3 different graphs to a carousel item in a carousel. But I am not sure how to bind 3 different data controls to it.

Every thing I've read only has you bind 1 data control to a carousel item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the carousel item as far as the model goes is based on a single collection and thus a single data control. You can add content of other data controls to the items, but this then requires you to manually synchronize the current displayed carousel item with the data to be displayed for it by the other data control.

Check this for a similar solution: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/81-master-detail-tab-with-graphs-394252.pdf